# Docker access to MySQL on host with php artisan migrate and giving access denied - what is actually going on at the network level?

Tags: mysql, docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

I was wondering if someone could quite clearly explain what is happening on a network level with all the components I have here so that I can understand what's happening when I troubleshoot these types of problems :)

- I have a mac. I installed Docker (boot2docker).
- I started a docker machine.
- I have a mysql docker image that I have started in my docker machine.
- I have mysql workbench.
- I have an instruction to connect the workbench to the mysql in my    mysql image in my docker machine. It fails. (I use the docker-machine    IP).
- I have a php docker image.
- In this php image I am required to run "php artisan migrate" and this    fails to connect to the database with a PDO Exception - Access    denied. and some random IP I don't recognise in the error message.

How exactly do all these layers and IPs and network things fit together? Where might the random IP in the error message come from? I know there's a virtual box in the mix too. Please could someone explain all this to me?

Comment: Does the mysql-server listen on it's public IP-Adress? It might only listen on `127.0.0.1` or even socket-only.

Comment: How can I determine this?

Comment: Do you have a docker-compose.yml you could share?

Comment: Either check the mysqld config file or `netstat -tulpen | grep 3306` and check whether it says `127.0.0.1:3306` or `0.0.0.0:3306`

Comment: @Grimmy, I'm not using docker compose for this... it's all manual...

Comment: @Dee Then share the docker commands you used to start the container.

Comment: will do - and will reply to @tkausi when i can get netstat happening...

Comment: Ok so somehow starting everything from scratch got everything working. I would still like to know what's actually going on though like which parts are communicating with which parts and how and IP things. 
I couldn't get that netstat command working on the machine that had the issue.